# Twilio Notification Triggers - Subaccount Usage

Tags: twilio

I'd like to get an email notification from Twilio anytime a subaccount has used over 1,000 message units in a month. Is there a way to create a Twilio notification trigger that would do this? Currently, I have to go into the subaccount usage report in the console, run through about 15 pages of info looking for users that have run up a bill over $15 and check their individual usage to see if I need to up their pay tier.

Answer (score 1):

From the Twilio console, click the Billing (upper right corner) -> Usage -> Triggers. I can take some amount of time before the usage trigger fires, but it will fire.

Create a Usage Trigger

There is also an API so you can programmatically create the triggers in each sub-account.

[REST API: UsageTrigger](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-trigger)

[image]

Comment: How do I get it to monitor the subaccounts? I saw this, but it seems it will monitor the master or collectively all the accounts?

Comment: Did you try defining it at the sub account level?

Comment: Are you saying to create a trigger for each account?

Comment: Yes, correct. Either via the console or via the API.

Comment: Ok, I was looking for a trigger that would watch all subaccounts. With hundreds of them, this would be a very large task.

Comment: That is what the API is for.